# parse datetime resulting in ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I tried to parse a timestamp of a CSV file (first column named "time"). The timestamp has the format: `01.10.2016  00:10:00`  (`dd.mm.yyyy  HH:MM:SS`)

```
    timestamp_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S")
    df_pi_data = pd.read_csv( "pi_daten.csv", usecols = (0,1), sep =';', thousands='.',  decimal=',', names = ['time','temperature'], parse_dates=['time'], date_parser = timestamp_parser)
```

The following error occurs:

```
ValueError: time data '\xef\xbb\xbftime' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S'
```

@kantal:

```
 time;temperature;
 01.10.2016 00:00; 23,13854599;
 01.10.2016 00:10; 23,24945831;
 01.10.2016 00:20; 23,16853714;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse the column header as a time.

Comment: Please, show the first few lines of the file.

Comment: @kantal: Please see the edited post

Answer (score 0):

```
time;temperature
01.10.2016 00:00; 23,13854599
01.10.2016 00:10; 23,24945831
01.10.2016 00:20; 23,16853714
```

```py
import pandas as pd
timestamp_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M")
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=";", decimal=',', \
                 parse_dates=['time'], date_parser = timestamp_parser)
```

I use this data, and use the code, success working

```
    time    temperature
0   2016-10-01 00:00:00 23.138546
1   2016-10-01 00:10:00 23.249458
2   2016-10-01 00:20:00 23.168537
```

Comment: I tried, the result ist an error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

You have no 'seconds' in the data, so remove '%S' from 'timestamp_parser'.
And see the modified args in pd.read_csv below:

```
pd.read_csv("pi_daten.csv" , usecols = (0,1), \
             sep=r'\s*;\s*', engine="python", \
             thousands='.',  decimal=',',  \
             parse_dates=['time'], date_parser = timestamp_parser)
```

**Edit:**
A workaround for 'decimal' separator problem:

```
df["temperature"]= df.temperature.transform(lambda col: col.str.replace(',','.').astype(float))
```

Comment: I deleted the seconds and used your code, however this error pops up: ValueError: The 'decimal' option is not supported with the 'python' engine

Comment: Which pandaas version you have? Mine is  '0.25.3'.

Comment: '0.16.2' Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the version at the moment.

Comment: Try then without the 'engine' args.

Comment: Unfortunately, also not working: ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators, but this causes 'decimal' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine.
I think I give up, I will just read in this column as strings and the convert it afterwards, this is working. Indeed, it's an ugly solution.......